# What is the best way to send a big batch of files from a form?

Tags: php, html, forms, file-upload, photo

my father is a professional photographer and he has a form for ordering printed photos but you can only order one at the time and it is sent by email which I don't think can handle a lot of pictures.

Since I love designing websites and he has this problem I would love to help him and his business. The first and only solution I could came up with is uploading the pictures on a folder on his website so he can download them. But wont that slow down his website if too many people are uploading big files. Also he only has 15Gb website storage available which a big part of is already used by his own website and I think my website is also on the same space as his.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad English!

Comment: hosting with unlimited storage/fairuse plans start at $5/month.

Comment: Yeah, if you want to storage the files in the server, 15GB will not be enough.
Maybe you may put a lifetime limit to the files, deleting them after, for example, 24 hours.
But I think the best solution is too hire a unlimited hosting storage plan.

Comment: Why don't you consider an existing solution like Dropbox / Google Drive? Ask the clients to upload their photos there, then give you a link to it. It is easy, and will save you a ton of trouble. All you need to do is write good instructions on the website, and maybe provide a form to enter the URL of the folder.

Comment: There are several things to considder here. 1) HDD space on server 2) Data Traffic per month 3) Down- / Uploadspeed of server 4) Available RAM on server. Sure you can hire some cheap server with lots of storage. But if 10+ clients start uploading files, it'll slow down terribly which results in the loss of clients. It's probebly best to hire a dedicated server or host one colocated or at home if you've got fiber. Once you're prepared you can worrie about writing some nice website for it. There are some very nice AJAX scripts out there that could do exactly what you want.

Comment: Hey light, maybe I could use a dropbox api to upload it to my fathers dropbox? Or will that still affect the speed of the site.

Comment: I was just going to suggest similar as what @light said and what you said. Pay for a service that has an API and then make you're own interface via PHP.

Comment: @Florens What's the purpose of uploading it to your father's site? If the intent is for people to upload photos that you father can access, storing a copy of the Dropbox copy on the server seems redundant. I'd imagine downloading from Dropbox or a client's computer consumes roughly the same amount of bandwidth. I wouldn't recommend it. If you TRULY need the photos to be stored on the server for whatever reasons, you might as well go for a straight upload solution.

Comment: @light but if I upload it with the api to dropbox won't the upload be with the dropbox servers what means no load on my fathers server? If I upload it somewhere he's going to need to download it anyway. From his own site or his dropbox is almost the same except that dropbox wont slow the site down. Is that correct?

Comment: @Florens When a client uploads to Dropbox, the data is transferred between the client computer and Dropbox. It doesn't use your father's server's bandwidth. When your father downloads the files from Dropbox to his own computer, it is between Dropbox and his computer. Again, it doesn't consume any bandwidth on the server. And that is the reason why you use Dropbox. Your father's web server is not involved at all, and is freed up to do what you want it to do best - show people nice looking HTML pages. You really don't want it to be bogged down by heavy data transfers.

Comment: Ok, I guess I'm going to learn a bit about the dropbox api now. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: If I use a form to select files and then submit it to my dropbox php file, won't it upload the files to a temporary folder on my website and than to dropbox or is it straight to dropbox?